# PHP - Check that post exists then add item to shopping cart using getById function and addItem method

Tags: php

I've only been working with PHP for a couple of weeks. I'm stuck on something in this assignment that I know is probably very simple. Been at it for a few hours now with no luck. I'm coding a shopping cart and working in the index.php file, checking to make sure the id exists for the item a user has chosen. If it exists, then the item will be added to the shopping cart. My prof gave me a hint (included in code comments below) but I obviously don't understand.  Help with this would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<?php

require_once('session_util.php');

// if $id is not null, add the item with that id to the shopping cart
// (hint: use the getById function and the addItem method)
// You have id - so with id use getbyId to get item and then use addItem to put into cart.
// First, you must use the if statement to make sure the id exists.
// If it doesn't then you didn't get the post, do nothing

$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

if ($id!== null) {
    // add the item with the id to the shopping cart
   getById($id, $itemList);
   $cart[] = $item;
} else {
    // post doesn't exist, donothing();
}

?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Form 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>View Item</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        foreach ($itemList as $item)
            echo $item->getAsRow();
        ?>
    </table>
    <form id="checkout" method="post" action="checkout.php">
    <input id="submit" type="submit" name="checkout" value="checkout">
    </form>
</main>
</body>
</html>



here is the getById function written in my session_util.php file.  I apologize for not including it in the beginning. 

function getById(int $id, array $items)
    {
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            if ($item->getId() === $id) {
                return $item;
            }
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
```

```html
<?php

    class ShoppingCart
    {

        // Add a product to the cart
        public function addItem(Item $item)
        {
            // This puts the itemArray in an array called "cart"
            $cart = $this->getItemArray();
            // This puts the an item into "cart"
            $cart[] = $item;
            // This updates the itemArray by replacing it with "cart".
            $this->setItemArray($cart);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is `getById()` a class method or just a function? also post here `getById()`

Comment: it's just a function.  It's not included with my class methods and my prof did not say that I needed to add it.

Comment: you would obviously need to create a function `getById()` from where you can get item using `id` as `parameter`.
let me post some code example that may can help you.

Comment: I'm sorry.. The function was created in my session_util file..  I just found it.  Didn't even remember creating it.  But I have about 8 files and it's getting a bit overwhelming. I'm going to try to edit my original post to include it .

Comment: it would be good to move the function into `ShoppingCart` class as a class method as I posted in an answer below, check my answer.

Comment: I did and this caused other issues.  My prof looked at my files and said I only needed to edit my index file.  That's all the info he would give me (the comments I included in my code above)

Comment: does `$itemList` exists in your `session_util.php` file? or some other included file?

Comment: $itemList is my array that includes all items     $itemList = array();   located in the item_list.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Near the top code snippet, you are just calling the `getById` however I don't see you calling `addItem`.

Something like below should work - adapt it to your needs.

```
$shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();

if ($id!== null) {
   $item = $shoppingCart->getById($id, $itemList);
   $shoppingCart->addItem($item);
}
```

Comment: thanks for trying to help @Sushil.  I'm getting an error using your code ... "getById not found in ShoppingCart. Referenced method is not found in subject class"

Comment: If you don't have the `getById` method in your `ShoppingCart` class then that'd throw error - so you need to add that before you can use that method if you don't have it already.

Answer (score 0):

**index.php**: Then in your index.php file

```
global $itemList;

// create a class instance
$shoppingCart = new ShoppingCart();

$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

if ($id!== null) {
    // get the item using $id
    $item = getById($id, $itemList);
    // add the item
    $shoppingCart->addItem($item);
} else {
    // post doesn't exist, donothing();
}
```

Wrap it according to your own needs.

Comment: I appreciate this. I've made your suggested changes. I'm getting an error message over "$shoppingCart" on the line that reads 
$item= $shoppingCart->getById($id); ... "Required parameter $items  missing - Invocation parameter types are not compatible with declared" 
 I'm too new at this to understand what this means or  how to correct it

Comment: please edit your question post and add `getById()` in it.

Comment: I now realize that I have new problems because I moved the getById function into the shopping_cart class.  I wish my prof was more clear.  He said my other files were fine. I only need to edit code on index.php, according to him.

Comment: does your `getById()` returning something?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.  I have added the function to the bottom of my question and this function is located in my session_util.php file.    Are you requesting that I do something else?

Comment: please check my edited answer. it may help. while I don't exactly know what's inside your `getById()` function and from where `$itemList` is coming, but may be edited answer can help you.

Comment: Thank you. I will keep working on it.  I appreciate your effort to help me.